# execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to update the field in multiple records based on the `unique_pile_id__c` that is unique for all the multiple records. I am trying to write trigger like this:

```
trigger opMetricsTrigger on Operational_Metrics__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    Operational_Metrics__c[] op=null;
    Set<Id> opIds = new Set<Id>();
    public static boolean run = true;

    if(run)
    {
        run=false;
        for (Operational_Metrics__c e : Trigger.new) 
        {
            if(e.Unique_Pile_ID__c != null)
                opIds.add(e.Unique_Pile_ID__c );
        }

        Map<Id, Operational_Metrics__c> y = 
            new Map<Id, Operational_Metrics__c>([select Unique_Pile_ID__c,unique_id__C, 
                Project__c,Composting_Method__c,Pile_Monitoring_Date__c,Average_Temperature__c,
                Moisture_Test__c,Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c,Other_Action__c,
                Pile_Input_Register_Date__c,Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c,
                Pile_Completion_Stage__c,Date_Pile_COmpleted__c,Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c,
                No_of_Days__c  from operational_metrics__c 
                where Unique_Pile_ID__c in :opIds]);

        for (Operational_Metrics__c oc : [select Unique_Pile_ID__c,unique_id__C, 
            Project__c,Composting_Method__c,Pile_Monitoring_Date__c,Average_Temperature__c,
            Moisture_Test__c,Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c,Other_Action__c,
            Pile_Input_Register_Date__c,Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c,
            Pile_Completion_Stage__c,Date_Pile_COmpleted__c,Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c,
            No_of_Days__c  from operational_metrics__c where Unique_Pile_ID__c in :opIds]) 
        {
            System.debug('oc '+y.get(oc.Unique_Pile_ID__c));
        }


    }
}
```

But when I am saving a record it is throwing:

> `execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: 10-Ber1: External entry point`

Here 10-Ber1 is the `unique_pile_id__c`. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `opIds` variable is a set of IDs, and it sounds like you're passing in the string `10-Ber1` as an ID, when in reality it's a text value.

You need to change `Set<Id> opIds = new Set<Id>();` to `Set<string> opIds = new Set<string>();`