# Error "System.String Exception: Invalid Id :Second External Entry Point "

Tags: trigger, error, error-messages

Getting This Error For Only  1 Specific  Record 
this is my Trigger
It is Working fine for 500+ Records but, Only for One Record I Am  getting this Error

```
trigger Create_Payment_Schdule on Apartment_and_Allocation__c (After insert,After update) {

    Set<Id>set_Oppty = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id>set_Block = new Set<Id>();

    List<Payment_Schedule__c> pay_schdule = new List<Payment_Schedule__c>();

    for(Apartment_and_Allocation__c Ac: trigger.new)
    {
        set_oppty.add(Ac.Potential__c);
        set_Block.add(Ac.Block__c);
        system.debug('######################'+set_Block);
        List<Project_Milestone__c> pm = [SELECT Milestone_Rank__c,Name,Phase_Id__c,
            Phase__c,Project_Milestone_Percent__c,Project_Milestone_Status__c,
            Project_Milestone_Value__c,Project__c 
            FROM Project_Milestone__c 
            where Phase_Id__c =:Ac.Phase_Id__c ORDER BY CreatedDate ];

        system.debug('######################'+set_Oppty);

        List<Payment_schedule__C> Ps1 = [select Default_Milestone_Value__c,Status__c,
            Milestone_Percent__c,Milestone_Rank__c,potential__c  
            From Payment_schedule__c 
            where potential__c =:set_Oppty];

        system.debug('######################'+pm.size());

        if(ac.A_A_Status__c == 'Sold' && ac.Create_Schedule__c == true){
            for(integer i = 0; i < pm.size(); i++)
            {
                system.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + ps1.size());
                if(ps1.size() == 0){
                    Payment_Schedule__c ps = new Payment_Schedule__c();
                    ps.Potential__c = Ac.Potential__c;
                    ps.name = pm[i].name; 
                    ps.Status__c = pm[i].Project_Milestone_Status__c;
                    // ps.Phase_id1__c = ac.Phase_Id__c;
                    pay_schdule.add(ps);
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    insert pay_schdule ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41984/execution-of-beforeupdate-caused-by-system-stringexception-invalid-id-in-trig

Comment: What line causes the error?  Does the "update" case work and the "insert" case fail?